How to get .angular/cache folder back?
I was upgrading my angular project from v8 to v17. At the end of upgrade I found .angular folder and I've deleted the .angular folder from my project since my project compiling time has increased. Even after deleting .angular` folder, my project compiling time has remained same. But, in this process I lost the .angular/cache folder. I found that .angular/cache enhances the performance. Is there a way to get back the .angular/cache folder?

Try checking out the angular docs for ng cache
ENABLE

Enables disk cache for all projects in the workspace.

ng cache enable
ng cache on

Cache will get generated when you run the application (ng serve) command or npm run start!

Deleting .angular/cache folder in application doesn't make any difference? Because, at the end we have to run ng serve.

@Eranki If you change something without the server running will not be present on the cache, so its better to recreate the cache during start of the angular DEV server!

I disabled the cache in my angular.json. That was preventing me from creating .angular/cache. I reverted that change and got the folder back after running the server. It regenerated.
